# jQuery - Detached anchor content remains focused on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I encountered another problem related to Internet Explorer. This browser is really a curse for internet users and webdesigners!
The issue I'm having now is that when a link image which has a rollover effect gets clicked, the whole parent container is being detached to another position but still looks like I hold my mouse over it.

Please follow [this link](http://www.mediaheart.ro/) and click any button from the left side ( ie. 'Profil', 'Servicii','Portofoliu' or 'Recomandari' ) and pay attention to the way it appears after the detach.

What should I do?

*Later edit: I've updated the link*

Comment: Which version of IE? No differences at all here, between IE9 and Chrome (on Windows 7)

Comment: @FloydPink I've made some changes immediately after I posted this question, that's why it looked allright for you. If you may, you can take a look now. It happens on most versions of IE, from 7 to 9.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I managed to find a solution by myself. I've deleted the `a.someclass:hover` properties and added them through jQuery `mouseover()`. The problem with the hover state being always activated after the `detach()` has been solved by removing css properties with `click()`.

So, all good now. Thanks anyway.